# Rule of sum problem

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

I am supposed to solve the following problem:

> How many different 4-digit numbers exist, which sum is 9 and do not
>   contain the number 0.

My solution:

$\frac{4!}{3!}+\frac{4!}{3!}+\frac{4!}{2!}+\frac{4!}{2!}+\frac{4!}{2!}=44$

My approach: I tried to write all possible combinations:

$$6 1 1 1=\frac{4!}{3!}\\5211=\frac{4!}{2!}\\4311=\frac{4!}{2!}\\4221=\frac{4!}{2!}\\3222=\frac{4!}{3!}$$

Comment: I don't follow where you got your numbers from and so cannot immediately verify the correctness of your solution without doing my own calculations.  As for a hint on a more standard approach, the search term would be "stars and bars."

Comment: What lead you to that solution strategy?  44 isn't the right answer.  I'd love to help you see where you went astray, but I can't guess what lead you to this calculation.

Comment: @JMoravitz, I edited my question so you can see the solution

Comment: @MatthewDaly I edited my question so you can see the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the four-digit number is written like $ABCD$, then you are looking for the number of ways to solve the equation $A+B+C+D=9$ in positive integers.  Because it's easier to work with non-negative numbers (for reasons we'll see shortly), let's set $A'=A-1$, $B'=B-1$, $C'=C-1$, $D'=D-1$.  Now we need to find the number of solutions to $$A'+B'+C'+D'=5$$ in non-negative integers.

This is easily addressed with the [stars-and-bars strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).  It's worth reading to get all the detail, but essentially there is a one-to-one correspondence between solutions to that equation and ways to arrange five * and three | in a line.  For instance, the solution $(A',B',C',D')=(3,0,2,0)$ corresponds to the arrangement * * * | | * * | and vice-versa.  However, the number of arrangements of those characters is easily seen to be $\binom83=56$ since you just need to choose which of the 8 characters in the string need to be filled with the bars.

---

Your solution  strategy would have been fine if you had included all the possible digit combinations.  You're missing 3321, which accounts for why you had 12 fewer solutions than the correct answer.

Comment: Thank you, so if I am getting it right, if there would 5 digit numbers I would use $\binom84$?

Comment: @Daniel That's right!  A nice thing about standard combinatorial strategies is that it keeps you from having to think of all the combinations yourself.

Comment: But how this strategy consider, that there should be sum 9?

Comment: @Daniel the fact that the digits add up to $9$ is accounted for in the top number in the binomial coefficient, it being $9-1=8$.  For additional example, had we been looking for $3$-digit numbers without zeroes whose digit sum was $6$ instead it would have been $\binom{6-1}{2}=10$.  Note that the problem becomes more challenging when we are looking for numbers whose digit sum is greater than $9$ as the outcomes counted might have included where one of the digits was *larger than nine*, which isn't possible in base10.  We would usually correct that by using inclusion-exclusion.

Comment: @JMoravitz oh okay, thanks, I first thought that it is because of the digits from 1 to 9. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you can find the number of tuples $(a,b,c,d)$ where $a,b,c,d$ are positive integers that satisfy: $$a+b+c+d=9$$ then you are ready.

This because then automatically $a,b,c,d\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$ so that string $abcd$ can be recognized as a $4$-digit number that does not contain digit $0$.

Use [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) for this.

Comment: Thank you so much